# how to configure Mac OS X Sierra for syslog or unified log forwarding

Tags: macos, syslog, plist

I am trying to perform syslog forwarding. But after launching `plist` like this:

```
launchctl unload/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist
```

I get this error:

> /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist: Operation not
>   permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged

Answer (score 0):

System Integrity Protection is enabled by default to not allow root access to change certain resources. You can turn System Integrity Protection on or off using these steps.
1) From the Apple menu, choose “Restart…” > “Restart“.
2) Simultaneously press and hold the “Command” and “R” buttons. This will start you in Recovery Mode.
3) Select “Utilities” > “Terminal“.
4) Type one of the following, then press “Enter“:
Disable System Integrity Protection: csrutil disable
Enable System Integrity Protection: csrutil enable
5) Restart the computer again, and the change will be made.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Copying and pasting information from another place without attribution is *plagiarism*, and is not permitted here. Please edit your answer to include the source of information. Thanks!